# PHP Variable in substr() as length not executing

Tags: php, string, substr

I am having a rookie level question but this is tricking me out. I am using substr() from PHP and passing string text and length both in PHP variable.

Somehow the length part is not being executed as php variable into this function. Can I get some insights on this and how to execute this.

`$display_string = substr($video_topics,$display_length);` where `$video_topics` is the main string and `$display_length` is the integer which is not executing.

Comment: What is the value of `$display_length` ?

Comment: Read please [mcve] and __update__ your question.

Comment: `$video_topics ="azertqsdfazert"; $display_length = 5; $display_string = substr($video_topics,$display_length); echo $display_string;` works well

Answer (score 0):

Guess from the variable name, what you want may be:

```
$display_string = substr($video_topics, 0, $display_length);
```

The second parameter is the offset and the third one is the length.